# 2 docker контейнера на одном IP адресе

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

пытаюсь собрать веб приложение с mysql в докере, мой docker-compose выглядит так

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/clients_base
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
     - /db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST='localhost'
      - MYSQL_USER='user'
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD='password'
      - MYSQL_DB='db'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'     
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

При запуске, получаю ошибку коннекта к бд "Host '172.18.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server", что очевидно.
Можно ли это решить, не давая грант конкретному юзеру на коннект с любого IP адреса?

Пробовал указывать docker-compose MYSQL_HOST: db и в настройках приложения такой же localhost - не сработало, т.к на нем нет сокета mysqld

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В настройках `Django` в качестве `HOST`'а базы данных Вы должны указать имя сервиса:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST': 'db',
        ...
    }
}
```

Открывать доступ извне к `MySQL` при этом совсем необязательно:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/clients_base
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
     - /db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST='db'
      - MYSQL_USER='user'
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD='password'
      - MYSQL_DB='db'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
```